# C# Language Enum Declaration

Tags: c#, dll

Hi Is there a way to declare  an enum or to customize the way of declaring an enum which returns an object in C#?

```
private enum testEnum
{ 
    firstname =1 
    ,lastname = 2
}
```

and if we want to return the names rather than 1 and 2 ? 
like testEnum.firstname returns 1 .

I want to declare an enum to return objects like in Java . is it possible?

Comment: can you show what you have or a pseudo code of what you want to do?

Comment: private enum testEnum{ firstname =1 ,lastname = 2} and if we want to return the names rather than 1 and 2 ? like testEnum.firstname returns 1 . i want to declare an enum to return objects like in Java . is it possible?

Comment: So you're trying to box an enum into a reference type, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public class NameEnum
{
    static NameEnum()
    {
        FirstName = new NameEnum("FirstName");
        LastName = new NameEnum("LastName");
    }

    public static NameEnum FirstName { get; private set; }
    public static NameEnum LastName { get; private set; }

    private NameEnum(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Is that close enough?

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.enum.aspx

An enumeration is a set of named constants whose underlying type is any integral type except Char. If no underlying type is explicitly declared, Int32 is used. Enum is the base class for all enumerations in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use interfaces for this:

```
interface IColorEnum {};

class ColorEnum: IColorEnum
{
    public static const Red = new ColorEnum();
    public static const Green = new ColorEnum();
    public static const Blue = new ColorEnum();
};
```

And use it like usual:

```
void foo(IColorEnum color)
{
    if(color == ColorEnum.Red) {...}
}
```

**Update+improve**: you can even drop interface and just use class with couple of public static fields with type of this class and private constructor to prevent creating new instances of it:

```
class ColorEnum
{
    private ColorEnum() {};
    public static const Red = new ColorEnum();
    public static const Green = new ColorEnum();
    public static const Blue = new ColorEnum();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) state:

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char.

Assuming you mean `object` to be complex/reference type. then the answer to your question is no. You could always create a class with named properties containing reference types.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only possible in java.

It seems that you want to implement singleton the Joshua Bloch way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you be a class exposing static fields that can then be of any type you want.